# Flutter custom painter line like word search

Tags: flutter, paint

I try to make a word game for test purpose. I already make the puzzle using listview builder. But didnot able to make the selectable lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomPaint in a stack with your other widget:

```
CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: LinesPainter(),
      ),
```

Then in your lines painter you can use:

```
    void drawRect (
  Rect rect,
  Paint paint
)
```

to draw a filled transparent rectangle between pointer down and current pointer